# Checkbox is checked, but :checked doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few checkboxes. I'm setting and resetting the default values of the checkboxes with the .prop() function, based on a JSON response (loading the data via ajax-requests). The problem is, that they apparently don't change this behaviour, if I change them manually. I can't pass the value of the checkboxes via $('#checkbox :checked').val(), a console log says 'undefined'. Is this because of the .prop() function? How can I get the value of the checked checkboxes?

If you need more information, i'll gladly provide them.
Here some code:

```
if (json.event.public_visible == 1) {
  $('#event_public_visible').prop('checked', true);
} else {
  $('#event_public_visible').prop('checked', false);
}

if (json.event.package_event == 1) {
  $('#event_package_only').prop('checked', true);
} else {
  $('#event_package_only').prop('checked', false);
}
```

Update: more code

```
var editEvent = function () {
  if ($('#event_public_visible').is(':checked')) {
    console.log('test');
  }
  formData = {
    // ... other fields
    event_package_only: $('#event_package_only :checked').val(),
    event_public_visible: $('#event_public_visible :checked').val(),
    // ... more fields
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: base_url + "admin/events/editAsync",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
      // success handling
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: It should work - post the actual JavaScript involved, the code that tries to use `:checked`.

Comment: Also note that it should be `$('#checkbox-id:checked').val()`, with no space before the `:checked`.

Comment: did you try .is(':checked')?

Comment: Also also, you're doing the right thing using `.prop()` in this case.

Comment: @drTerminal yep, tried that, not working...

Comment: @Pointy added the bit of code, that uses the :checked stuff.

Comment: Get rid of the space in your jQuery selector - the `:checked` should immediately follow the element id.  With a space, it means "look for a checked checkbox **descendant element** of the element with id 'event_package_only'".

Comment: @Pointy still 'undefined'. Who knows what chaos I produced here, lol

Comment: I'm stupid. I console.logged the wrong Id -.- it works with the removed space before :checked. Sorry and thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a property on elements with an IDs of 'event_public_visible' and 'event_package_only' and then trying to read from an element of ID 'checkbox'.

Did you mean to use this?

```
$('[type=checkbox]:checked').val()
```

Can see it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vRba3/

Comment: the 'checkbox' was just an example :) sorry for the confuzzling writing there

Comment: Then it's likely your space before the :checked selector, remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:   `$('#event_public_visible:checked').val()` and `$('#event_public_visible:checked').val()`

You can try: `('#event_public_visible:checked').length ? $('#event_public_visible:checked').val() : '';`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/SfcjG/

Comment: It was the space before the ':checked'. Thanks for your answer, though :)